# How can I create a panda Serie from two series, selecting the first matching element in the second file from a common column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

Bonjour !

I'm developing a easy driving simulator with psychopy.

I set (traffic) lights around the window, and they are lighting on and off.
The light and the colour are randomly generated.

The lights can be RED, ORANGE or GREEN when on, and GREY when off
When the light is RED, the user has to press the spacebar, otherwise no key should be pressed.

Then, I would like to :

- dataframe LIGHTS_list :record each light switching on and off ✅
- dataframe KEYS_list : record each key pressed ✅
- dataframe LIGHT_trial : match the first key pressed during the light on ❌
- dataframe LIGHT_trial : if no key pressed, write "nothing" ❌
- dataframe LIGHT_trial : check if the first key pressed is the one expected ✅❌ (the function works but isn't correctly implemented, because of the two previous steps)

## if you need to see the variables declarations:

```
    # --------- TABLE LIGHT components
    EVENT_list= pd.DataFrame (columns = ["frame","trigger","lightON","lightCOLOUR","keypressed","result"]) #initializing the list for the FRAMES when a new action is recorded
    LIGHTS_list = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["LIGHT name","LIGHT colour","lightON", "LIGHT time off", "action required"])
    KEYS_list = pd.DataFrame(columns =["lightON","KEY name", "KEY pressed time", "KEY duration"]) #------------------- ATTENTION, j'ai ajouté lightON pour merger les tableaux en light_trial
    light_trial = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["LIGHT name","LIGHT colour","LIGHT time on", "LIGHT time off", "action required","KEY name", "KEY pressed time", "KEY duration"]) #------------------------ATTENTION, action result removed after KEYNAME for test merging
```

## EXAMPLE

### LIGHTS_list :

[image: LIGHTS_list on Excel]

LIGHT name - LIGHT colour - lightON - LIGHT time off - action required

lightBB - green - 0.0233359 - 0.9297223 - nothing

lightRG - green - 1.9957957 - 2.8119444 - nothing

lightLF - orange    - 3.8795967 - 4.7616028 - nothing

lightRG - red   - 5.87728   - 6.6938645 - space

### KEYS_list :

[image: KEYS_list on Excel]

lightON - KEY name  - KEY pressed time  - KEY duration

0.0233359   - a - 1.005227  - 0.1171798

1.9957957   - z - 2.5968278 - 0.1431718

3.8795967   - e - 4.1282927 - 0.1876447

3.8795967   - e - 4.827796  - 0.1544934

5.87728 - r - 6.4868242 - 0.1813495

5.87728 - escape    - 7.1298663 - 0.1340118

### WISH : LIGHT_trial :

LIGHT name - LIGHT colour - lightON - LIGHT time off - action required - KEY name   - action result - KEY pressed time  - KEY duration

lightBB - green - 0.0233359 - 0.9297223 - nothing - a   - WRONG - 1.005227  - 0.1171798

lightRG - green - 1.9957957 - 2.8119444 - nothing - z   - WRONG - 2.5968278 - 0.1431718

lightLF - orange    - 3.8795967 - 4.7616028 - nothing  - e  - WRONG - 4.1282927 - 0.1876447

lightRG - red   - 5.87728   - 6.6938645 - space - r - WRONG - 6.4868242 - 0.1813495

## then, here is the code I've written so far and I'm totally lost#

'''

```
    ######### FILE 7 : LIGHTS-KEYS TRIAL ###########
    # data to be written row-wise in csv file
    '''
    for each key pressed (KEY_list) take the time it was pressed
    and  check if it is between LIGHT ON && LIGHT OFF of each light in LIGHT_list
    
    if OKAY, take the first KEY and create the TRIAL entry
    '''

    #"""
    
    i = 0
    j = 0
    
    thislight=pd.DataFrame(columns=['lightname','lightcolour','timeON','timeOFF','actionrequired'])
    print('type', type(thislight))
    print("empty this light",thislight)
    keysoflight = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lightON','keyname', 'keytime', 'keydur'])
    
    
    while i  < len(LIGHTS_list):
    
        for index, LIGHTrow in LIGHTS_list.iterrows() :
            lightname = LIGHTS_list["LIGHT name"].iloc[i]
            lightcolour = LIGHTS_list["LIGHT colour"].iloc[i]
            timeON = LIGHTS_list['lightON'].iloc[i]
            timeOFF = LIGHTS_list['LIGHT time off'].iloc[i]
            actionrequired = LIGHTS_list["action required"].iloc[i]
            keyname = ''
            keypressedtime = 0.0
            keyduration = 0.0
            actionresult='none'
    
            thislight = pd.Series([lightname, lightcolour, timeON, timeOFF,        actionrequired],index=thislight.columns)
            print("add light in this light")
            print(thislight)
            
            while j < len(KEYS_list):
                for index, KEYrow in KEYS_list.iterrows():
                    lightTimeOn = KEYrow["lightON"]
                    keyname = KEYrow["KEY name"]
                    keypressedtime = KEYS_list["KEY pressed time"].iloc[index]
                    keyduration = KEYrow["KEY duration"]
    
                    if lightTimeOn == timeON:
                         print ("light ",i, "start :",timeON, "lightTimeOn",lightTimeOn,        "key:",keyname,"pressed:", keypressedtime, "stop:",timeOFF)
                         keygroupitem= pd.Series([lightTimeOn, keyname, keypressedtime, keyduration],         index=keysoflight.columns)
                 keysoflight = keysoflight.append(keygroupitem, ignore_index=True)
                 actionresult = result_light_keyboard(lightcolour,keyname)
            """
            if keypressedtime <= timeOFF and keypressedtime >= timeON:
                print ("light ",i, "start :",timeON, "key:",keyname,"pressed:", keypressedtime, "stop:",timeOFF)
                keygroupitem= pd.Series([keyname, keypressedtime, keyduration], index=keysoflight.columns)
                keysoflight = keysoflight.append(keygroupitem, ignore_index=True)
                actionresult = result_light_keyboard(lightcolour,keyname)
            """
            print(keysoflight)
            #keysoflight = keysoflight.iloc[0]

            #keysoflight= KEYS_list[KEYS_list['KEY pressed time'].between(timeON, timeOFF)]
            #keysoflight = keysoflight.iloc[0]
            #print(keysoflight)

        j=j+1
    #lighttrial_entry = pd.Series([lightname,lightcolour,timeON,timeOFF,actionrequired,keyname,actionresult,keypressedtime,keyduration],index=light_trial.columns)
    lighttrial_entry = pd.Series([lightname,lightcolour,timeON,timeOFF,actionrequired,keyname,keypressedtime,keyduration],index=light_trial.columns)
    light_trial = light_trial.append(lighttrial_entry, ignore_index=True)
    #keysoflight = pd.DataFrame(columns=["keyname", "keytime", "keydur"])
    i = i+1
    j = 0

        #lON = LIGHT_list["lightCOLOUR"].iloc[-1]
        #for key in KEY_list :

    #    each LIGHT, retreive all the [KEYS] pressed during ON && OFF
    #show the first one
    
    """
    LIGHTS_list["LIGHT name","LIGHT colour","LIGHT time on", "LIGHT time off", "action required"])
    KEYS_list = ["KEY name", "KEY pressed time", "KEY duration"])
    light_trial =["LIGHT name","LIGHT colour","LIGHT time on", "LIGHT time off", "action required","KEY name","action result", "KEY pressed time", "KEY duration"
    """
            #light_trial = light_trial.drop(light_trial[(light_trial['KEY pressed time'] > light_trial['LIGHT time off']) & (light_trial['KEY pressed time'] < light_trial['LIGHT time on']) ].index)
    #"""
    #light_trial = LIGHTS_list.merge(KEYS_list, on='lightON') #------------------- NE MET PAS LES LUMIERES QUI N'ONT PAS EU DE TOUCHE
    #light_trial = pd.concat([LIGHTS_list, KEYS_list], axis=1, join='inner')

    light_trial.to_csv('lights-trial.csv',index=False,header=True)
    '''
```

### printing output

```
    type <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
    empty this light Empty DataFrame
    Index: []
    add light in this light
    lightname           lightBB
    lightcolour           green
    timeON            0.0233359
    timeOFF            0.929722
    actionrequired      nothing
    dtype: object
    light  0 start : 0.023335899924859405 lightTimeOn 0.023335899924859405 key: a pressed: 1.0052269999869168 stop: 0.9297222999157384
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    light  0 start : 0.023335899924859405 lightTimeOn 0.023335899924859405 key: a pressed: 1.0052269999869168 stop: 0.9297222999157384
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    light  0 start : 0.023335899924859405 lightTimeOn 0.023335899924859405 key: a pressed: 1.0052269999869168 stop: 0.9297222999157384
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    light  0 start : 0.023335899924859405 lightTimeOn 0.023335899924859405 key: a pressed: 1.0052269999869168 stop: 0.9297222999157384
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    light  0 start : 0.023335899924859405 lightTimeOn 0.023335899924859405 key: a pressed: 1.0052269999869168 stop: 0.9297222999157384
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    4  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    4  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    4  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    4  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    4  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    4  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    light  0 start : 0.023335899924859405 lightTimeOn 0.023335899924859405 key: a pressed: 1.0052269999869168 stop: 0.9297222999157384
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    4  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    5  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    4  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    5  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    4  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    5  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    4  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    5  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    4  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    5  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
        lightON keyname   keytime   keydur
    0  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    1  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    2  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    3  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    4  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    5  0.023336       a  1.005227  0.11718
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\melis\Google Drive (ethical.sun.laoshi@gmail.com)\Aïna\Project-MT\full (ugly).py", line 699, in <module>
        thislight = pd.Series([lightname, lightcolour, timeON, timeOFF, actionrequired],index=thislight.columns)
      File "C:\Program Files\PsychoPy3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4372, in __getattr__
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
    AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'
    ##### Experiment ended. #####
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeed !

Here is the new code :

```
    import pandas as pd

def result_light_keyboard(lightcolour,key):
    if lightcolour == "red":
        if key == "space":
            return "GOOD"
        if key == None:
            return "space bar no pressed"
        else :
            return "wrong key"
    if lightcolour == "green" or "orange":
        if key == "None":
            return "GOOD"
        else:
            return "COLOR action denied"
    if lightcolour == "grey":
        if key == None :
            return "GOOD"
        else :
            return "GREY action denied"

LIGHTS = [['lightRF', 'red',0.0144022,0.9848114,'space'],
    ['lightTG','green',2.1786852,3.1140804,'nothing'],
    ['lightTA','orange',4.2440757,5.1936581,'nothing'],
    ['lightLE','green',6.3274216,7.2436572,'nothing']]

KEYS = [[0.0144022,'space',1.4684641,0.1541382],
    [2.1786852,'a',3.2867979,0.1812322],
    [2.1786852,'b',4.0286797,0.1812322],
    [4.2440757,'z',5.2329535,0.2139871],
    [6.3274216,'e',7.495657,0.2239251]]


LIGHTS_list = pd.DataFrame(LIGHTS, columns = ["LIGHT name","LIGHT colour","lightON", "LIGHT time off", "action required"])
KEYS_list = pd.DataFrame(KEYS, columns =["lightON","KEY name", "KEY pressed time", "KEY duration"])
light_trial = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["LIGHT name","LIGHT colour","LIGHT time on", "LIGHT time off", "action required","KEY name", "action result", "KEY pressed time", "KEY duration"])


singlelight=pd.DataFrame(columns=['lightname','lightcolour','timeON','timeOFF','actionrequired'])
keysoflight = pd.DataFrame(columns=['lightON','keyname', 'keytime', 'keydur'])


for index, LIGHTrow in LIGHTS_list.iterrows() :

    lightname = LIGHTrow["LIGHT name"]
    lightcolour = LIGHTrow["LIGHT colour"]
    timeON = LIGHTrow['lightON']
    timeOFF = LIGHTrow['LIGHT time off']
    actionrequired = LIGHTrow["action required"]
    keyname = ''
    keypressedtime = 0.0
    keyduration = 0.0
    actionresult='none'

    print("**********************************************")
    print("****** C U R R E N T  L I G H T :", index," - ", lightname, "****************")
    thislight = pd.Series([lightname, lightcolour, timeON, timeOFF, actionrequired],index=singlelight.columns)

    if any(timeON in sublist for sublist in KEYS) :
        for KEYrow in KEYS:
                lightTimeOn = KEYrow[0]
                keyname = KEYrow[1]
                keypressedtime = KEYrow[2]
                keyduration = KEYrow[3]

                if lightTimeOn == timeON and lightTimeOn <= timeOFF:
                    keygroupitem= pd.Series([lightTimeOn, keyname, keypressedtime, keyduration], index=keysoflight.columns)
                    keysoflight = keysoflight.append(keygroupitem, ignore_index=True)

                    print("keys for ", lightname)
                    print(keysoflight)

                    #the first key pressed for this light is : keysoflight[0], PUT IT in variable  and add to LIGHT TRIAL
                    firstkey = pd.Series(keysoflight.iloc[0], index=keysoflight.columns)
                    print("my fist key is : ",firstkey)
                    lighttrial_entry = pd.Series([lightname,lightcolour,timeON,timeOFF,actionrequired,firstkey['keyname'],result_light_keyboard(lightcolour,firstkey['keyname']), firstkey['keytime'],firstkey['keydur']],index=light_trial.columns)



    else :
        lighttrial_entry = pd.Series([lightname,lightcolour,timeON,timeOFF,actionrequired,"None",result_light_keyboard(lightcolour,"None"), "-","-"],index=light_trial.columns)

    keysoflight.drop(keysoflight.index, inplace=True)
    light_trial = light_trial.append(lighttrial_entry, ignore_index=True)

print( '------------------------------------------------------------')
print(light_trial['LIGHT colour'].to_string(index=False))
print('/\\')
print(light_trial['KEY name'].to_string(index=False))
print('/\\')
print(light_trial["action result"].to_string(index=False))
print( '------------------------------------------------------------')


print(light_trial)
#if 4.2440757 not in KEYS_list :
#    lighttrial_entry = pd.Series([lightname,lightcolour,timeON,timeOFF,actionrequired,"None",result_light_keyboard(lightcolour,"None"), "-","-"],index=light_trial.columns)
#    print(lighttrial_entry)
```

I can list the lights (my main code will record the random lights  as initially)
I can list the keys pressed by the user

And I can create a list with the first key pressed when the light was switched on.

I hope this can help someone later !